# Show data from multiple Items Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating a new rails app. In that I have 4 things Quotes, Images, Facts, Jokes. Each thing have its own controller, model file. So if I want to see quotes submitted by user I can go to localhost:3000/quotes and same with other things. Now What I want is to show all this 4 things on one page. All 4 things should be displayed in order they was created. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Sumeet

Comment: I recommend finding a Rails tutorial and starting from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you're viewing your Quotes **index view** at `localhost:3000/quotes` and you want to display quotes, images, facts and jokes altogether on this view. You should make sure you pass all these as instance variables to your **index function** in your **quotes controller**.

In your quotes **controller** make sure the index function is as following:

```
def index
  @quotes = Quote.all.order("created_at ASC")
  @images = Image.all.order("created_at ASC")
  @facts = Fact.all.order("created_at ASC")
  @jokes = Joke.all.order("created_at ASC")
end
```

In your index **view** now you can simply loop over them. The following is an example of how to do so with @quotes (you can follow the same for all other instances):

```
<% @quotes.each do |quote| %>
  <%= quote.content %>
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi I tried this but getting error undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass What I did is crated new controller and posted the code 'def index
  @quotes = Quote.all.order("created_at ASC")
  @images = Image.all.order("created_at ASC")
  @facts = Fact.all.order("created_at ASC")
  @jokes = Joke.all.order("created_at ASC")
end'

Comment: Hi, Its working. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. add dedicated controller (for instance `SummaryController`)
2. load all data models in its show action
3. use presenter or whatever else to sort them (models) by time of creation
4. pass models to newly created show view (`app/summary/show`)
5. DRY - so try to render those items via partials you already have.
   for example - render quotes using the same partials you have defined in     `app/views/quotes`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Problem solved.